# FBO to separate textures

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, fbo

How do I set FBO so it renders depth and color buffer in two separate textures, in one rendering pass ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just attach a suitable texture to the FBOs depth attachment point:

```
      glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT,GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId, 0);
```

.. and another texture to the color attachment point. See [this for more information](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html).